# Abort AWS publishing from visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, amazon-web-services, aws-cli

What can I do, if I want to **abort** publishing process on AWS EB, started from Visual studio.
I tried <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Break</kbd>, but it is not working for AWS cli.